# How to generate separate violinplots for each class and group

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, violin-plot

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df['Label'] = np.random.randint(0,2,size=100)
```

I would like to create a figure in python where x-axis shows the class labels ('Class 0' and 'Class 1') and for each class and for a pre-defined variable like 'B' the violin plot (with a box-plot inside) is created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to convert the dataframe to a long format with [`panda.DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and then plot with [`seaborn.violinplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html) or [`seaborn.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html).
- `pandas 1.3.0`, `seaborn 0.11.1`, `matplotlib 3.4.2`

### Import and DataFrame

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df['Class'] = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=100)

# melt the dataframe to a long form
dfm = df.melt(id_vars='Class', var_name='Group')

# display(dfm.head())
   Class Group  value
0      1     A     12
1      1     A     43
2      0     A     58
3      1     A     49
4      1     A     47
```

### Plotting

#### `seaborn.violinplot`

```
p = sns.violinplot(data=dfm, x='Group', y='value', hue='Class')
p.legend(title='Class', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc='upper left')
```

- With `x='Group', hue='Class'`

[image]

- With `x='Class', hue='Group'`

[image]

#### `seaborn.catplot`

- To easily plot separately for each group, use [`seaborn.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) with `kind='violin'`

```py
sns.catplot(kind='violin', data=dfm, x='Class', y='value', col='Group', col_wrap=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html), it is pretty straightforward:

```py
import seaborn as sns
...
sns.violinplot(x=df.Label, y=df.B)
```